# How can I set the field unique in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model class:

```
class PysicalServer(models.Model):

    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=64)  # I want to add the unique
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

I know use the primary_key can set unique, but the serial_number is not my id field, I can not use the primary_key, is there other property I can set field unique?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Just add `unique=True` in the field, so:

```py
serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
```

Refer [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#unique) for more information.

Comment: How to do this so it doesn't work with Dog and dog? So if I write one with the name dog, then Dog will not work next time, or DoG doG dOg will not work either, how can I do this?

Comment: this is an old answer, but probably you would want to convert all yours entries to lower case

Comment: I found the solution for this, but forgot were I found it. *capitalizeFirtChar = lambda s: s[:1].upper() + s[1:]*                                                             **def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        self.name = self.name.lower()
        self.name = capitalizeFirtChar(self.name)

        # If the name already exists
        if not Category.objects.filter(name__iexact=self.name).exists():
            super(Category, self).save(force_insert, force_update)**

Comment: very careful with that pre-hook, probably you're adding more queries to your lookup an thuis making slower request

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by the other stackoverflowers above, you can use `unique=True`. but mind you that this won't work if you want to set a joined unique constraint. For example, if you want a combination of fields to be unique, then you should use `models.UniqueConstraint` as seen below

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['title', 'sub_title'], name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_unique")
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 6):

The key word `unique=True` makes the `title CharField` unique.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-make-a-database-table-field-unique-in-Django.php

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a unique case insensitive, then do this.

example "my NamE is John" and "MY naME is jOHN" should match and will not work to have 2,

because if you write "my NamE is John" it will become "My name is john".

and "MY naME is jOHN" will also become "My name is john".

---

*models.py*

**1.** add this code to the top.

```
capitalizeFirstChar = lambda s: s[:1].upper() + s[1:]
```

---

**2.** Then here is an example how to use it.

```
    class MyModel(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
# The save method to convert your text "MY naME is jOHN" to "My name is john"

        def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
            self.name = self.name.lower()
            self.name = capitalizeFirstChar(self.name)
    
            # If the name already exists
            if not Category.objects.filter(name__iexact=self.name).exists():
                super(Category, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

---

This solution sucks if you don't want the characters to change in capitalisation.