# Create a customer in a Django webshop

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm working on a Django webshop and want to create a customer as in the title. I've made a login form in HTML and a respond in JSON back to the server.
Creating a new user in the database works fine.
Then there is the customer part, because if I don't assign a customer for each individual user I get an error: "User has no customer".
So I tried using this function to create a new customer in the database and assign it the newly created user.

```
c = Customer(user="Lukas", name="Lukas", email="lukas@lukasalstrup.dk", about="Account has just been created") # Create a new customer and assign the newly created user
c.save() # Save the customer in the system
```

When I do that I get an error:

```
Cannot assign "'Lukas'": "Customer.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

although I have a user called Lukas in the system. This will of course be changed later, but I just want to make it work, before I put in a variable.

My models.py customer class

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py register page:

```
def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')    
                messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + user)
                c = Customer(user="Lukas", name="Lukas", email="lukas@lukasalstrup.dk", about="Account has just been created") # Create a new customer and assign the newly created user
                c.save() # Save the customer in the system

                return redirect('login')
            


        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'store/register.html', context)
```

I have tried a couple of methods like changing the user to request.user anf {{request.user}}. None of these work. I can't find any documentation from Django covering that. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `user` should be a `User` object, so for example the logged in user:

```
def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + user)
            Customer.objects.create(
                user=user,
                name='Lukas',
                email='lukas@lukasalstrup.dk',
                about='Account has just been created'
            )
            return redirect('login')
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'store/register.html', context)
```

Comment: @Lukas: ah, that was because you assigned `user = form.cleaned_data['username']`, but it should be the result of `form.save()`.

Answer (score 0):

As Willem said, the user field must be a User object.

See below, assuming the `CreateUserForm()` creates a user object, this will return the created User object when you do `form.save()`.

```
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + user)
    Customer.objects.create(
        user=user,
        name='Lukas',
        email='lukas@lukasalstrup.dk',
        about='Account has just been created'
    )
    return redirect('login')
```

Without the form you would do:

```
user = User.objects.get(name='Lukas')  # I would not recommend name with .get()
c = Customer(user=user, name="Lukas", email="lukas@lukasalstrup.dk", about="Account has just been created") # Create a new customer and assign the newly created user
c.save() # Save the customer in the system
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remember to set `unique=True` somewhere on your `Customer` Model, otherwise you might end up returning more than one instance when filtering user by "Lukas", or whatever you decide to go with.

Comment: An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802099/how-can-i-set-the-field-unique-in-django), so you won't return 2 or more  "Lukas" objects on your query